# CNAME mapping to apps.facebook.com not working

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, cname

I'm having problems in mapping CNAME for apps.facebook.com
Here is my setup:
- I own domain called "example.us"
- I have forwarded my nameservers to Route53.
- I have created CNAME for "subdomain.example.us" -> "apps.facebook.com" (I have also tried by adding period at the end. ex:"apps.facebook.com.")

Here is what I expect:
- When I type "subdomain.example.us" in browsers, it should direct me to "apps.facebook.com"
- When I type "subdomain.example.us/appname" in browsers, it should direct me to   "apps.facebook.com/appname"

Here is what the actual results are:
- "subdomain.example.us" to going to "subdomain.facebook.com"
- "subdomain.example.us/appname" is going to "subdomain.facebook.com/appname"
- NOTE: When I use ping command, I can see it's going to apps.facebook.com.

```
$ping subdomain.example.us  
PING apps.facebook.com (69.171.228.28)
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I have configured the CNAME ?
Does Facebook allow CNAME to apps.facebook.com ?

-- Anil Madamala

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. It's required to have a Web-Server (i.e. Apache or other) where "subdomain.example.us" is configured as a virtual-host *OR* which accept any domain on a specific port (i.e. *:80). Then you will have what you expect.

But Facebook doesn't have "subdomain.example.us" configured at *their* web-servers.

All you can do is to have a simple redirect from your domain to the Facebook APP itself.